# How to Sort a Dictionary by Number Values Swift 4

Tags: swift

Hey the sorted dictionary method is putting the index in order based on the second and first value as 2 separate values like instead of going like this:

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15

**its doing this of this:**

slots:
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15

**it sorts like so:**

index: 0,1,11,12,13,14,15,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

I know it's weird but basically when the values get to 11 it thinks (1,1 / 11) is greater the number (2)

```
var sortedDict = [String: AnyObject]()

let arraySortedFromDict = sortedDict.sorted { $0.value.localizedCompare($1.value as! String) == .orderedAscending  }
```

Is there a better way to filter dictionary **Number** values in Swift **4**

Thanks,

Comment: why dont u make `var sortedDict = [Int: AnyObject]()`

Comment: yea, i have to have the key stay a string, though the value can change to a string instead of anyObject thought @aaisataev

Comment: Why do you use `AnyObject` although all values are obviously `String`? And even if the dictionary was heterogenous in Swift 3+ in most cases it's supposed to be `[String:Any]`.